# Unselected other items in recyclerview when selecting new item

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I've got a list of categories, in a horizontal recyclerview. I've made a selector as background, that swaps color on the item for when it's selected or not. But I want to do it so, when I click on a new item, the old item that was selected gets unselected. How would I do that? I've made a GIT repo describing my issue here:

https://github.com/Larrsenn/RecyclerViewTest

EDIT: 
After suggestion to put isSelected as a boolean flag on my ItemViewModel, it now also sometimes update other items that I haven't clicked on. I've updated the git-repo so you can see how it acts.

Comment: This answer of mine may help- https://stackoverflow.com/a/61169835/97714

Answer (score 1):

What I will Suggest is.

-> Suppose you have data for the Recyclerview like
RecyclerItemData, It should have one boolean flag, isSelected

-> isSelected = true (selected background is Visible)

-> isSelected = false (unselected bacground is visible)

-> Now When User click on recycler item, Pass RecyclerItemData's id for the clicked item to your activity via interface to method suppose (ItemClicked(String id)).

-> Now loop the wholelist, and for the wholelist make isSelected = false except for the item with the clcked id (for it make it true).

-> Now call adapter.notifydatasetchanged()

```
 //In onBindViewHolder() you should have code to handle isSelected flag, 
if(isSelected){
// Show selected background 
}else{
// Show unselected background
}
```

Changes required in you repo..

https://github.com/Larrsenn/RecyclerViewTest/blob/master/app/src/main/java/dk/larsen/testrecyclerview/MovieCategory.kt

```
data class MovieCategory(val id: Int, val title: String, var isSelected: Boolean)
```

When you are preparing list in addDataToRecycelrView() method here
https://github.com/Larrsenn/RecyclerViewTest/blob/master/app/src/main/java/dk/larsen/testrecyclerview/MainActivity.kt

set default value of isSelected to false for each item..

In Adapter class

```
fun bind(item: MovieCategoryItemViewModel) = with(itemView) {
        itemView.setOnClickListener {
            interaction?.onMovieCategoryItemSelected(item)
            // itemView.isSelected = true // remove this line..
        }
```

In adapter chaneg this to MovieCategory from MovieCategoryItemViewModel
      interface Interaction {
        fun onMovieCategoryItemSelected(item: MovieCategory)
      }

In MainActivity in method onMovieCategoryItemSelected

```
 override fun onMovieCategoryItemSelected(selectedItem:MovieCategory) {
 //        iterate current list of the adapter
    check for the item in the list where id == selectedItem
    for this item set iselected = true 
    else false
    now call diffutils update
  }
```

Comment: Cheers, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Hey, I did that and updated my git repo. It causes some of the items not selected, to also change color. Any ideas?

Comment: @MikkelLarsen make sure in onbindview you have handled the else case properly of unselection

Comment: Check out my git repo, I do make a foreach and loop over everything in the list before calling notifydatasetchanged. I tried changing the color manually, and that actually works fine. It's just when I say a selector it messes up. I'd like to do it with the selector :D